# How to stop logs from displaying in the terminal

Tags: linux

When I open an application from the terminal like jDeveloper, how do I stop the exception stacktrace within jdev from being displayed on the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using bash as your shell and that `jdev` is your executable

```
jdev  &> /dev/null
```

will not show anything in the terminal. If you just want to redirect stderr then you could do

```
jdev 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: I use csh. 'jdev >& /dev/null' worked. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction